# Parsing memory mapped file C

Tags: c, mmap, strtok

I'm currently building a functional DNS Server and I need some help to finish it. Currently I turn the server on and with the dig command I'm able to send my requests. The problem is how to answer them correctly. Before i have mapped in memory a file (using mmap) that contains domains names and their IP's, so if I receive any request regarding a local address I'm able to answer it by just parsing the mmaped file with a thread that gets the request from a linked list and extracting the needed information. I just can't seem to find a way to do it properly.

I'll leave my mmap code below:

```
void mmap_localdns(){
    int ldns;
    char *data;
    struct stat size;
    ldns=open("localdns.txt", O_RDONLY);
    stat("localdns.txt", &size);
    data = mmap((caddr_t)0, size.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, ldns, 0);
    close(ldns);
    printf("%s", data);

    char *pch;
    pch = strtok(&data, " ");

    while(pch != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    //munmap(data, size.st_size);
}
```

Tried using strtok() but it keeps giving me a Segmentation Fault. Perhaps it's not the best solution :/

The file I'm talking about follow these rules:

```
mywebserver.so.local 192.168.1.20
fileserver.so.local 192.168.1.10
ww5.so.local 192.168.1.5
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you really want to parse the file for each request? That sounds an awful lot of overhead. I think you should parse the file once, put the data in a hash table and then use that data structure. Also, what is your question?

Comment: `strtok` modifies the string being searched but the file has been mapped `PROT_READ` which is the likely reason for the seg fault. For such an application, IMHO there is not much advantage in using `mmap`. Better to use `fgets`. Also as already mentioned in the previous comment, it's not efficient to continuously parse. Just parse the file once (or whenever it changes) and use that result each time.

Comment: In the given code I start by mmaping the file and after that I try to parse it. My question is how to parse it correctly and what's the best way to store it so after I can easily get the answer to the requests. Plus, why is it giving me a seg fault.

Comment: @kaylum It's a school project so I have to use mmap :x I get it that it's better to parse it only once, but how should I do it? Only solution I found was strtok and it's not helping me.

Comment: Ok fair enough. Then you should open the file in writeable mode and do the mapping so that it is writeable. Also, you probably want to use MAP_PRIVATE rather than MAP_SHARED as you are unlikely to want the `strtok` processing to change the underlying file.

Comment: Regarding a single parsing - just create a data structure which stores the result of the parsing, do the parse once and from then on refer to the data structure rather than reparsing the file each time.

Comment: Just changed the PROT_READ to PROT_WRITE and the MAP_SHARED to MAP_PRIVATE and it is printing just as i wanted! Thanks alot @kaylum for the fast and really usefull response.

Comment: strtok happens to modify the char pointer address given to it which can cause segfaults if you're not careful to restore the char pointer address for other purposes. For example, set another char to equal the "data" address then after dealing with strtok on the "data" variable, set the "data" pointer address back to the address of the new char pointer

Comment: Don't use MAP_SHARED with PROT_WRITE since that will actually change the file (replacing the spaces with NULs) and then you'll have an invalid file for next time. You probably want to use MAP_PRIVATE which allows you to write to the memory but *doesn't* save the changes back to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening file with `O_RDONLY` flag, and mmap it with `PROT_READ` - which is all good. 
However, note that `strtok()` function will modify its argument.
In other words, you are breaking your promise to never write to memory location that mmap returned to you.

Solution is to use any memory routines that are truly read-only.